# How to show Timing command with more decimals?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, timing

I'm trying to compare the time that it takes to use the command LinearSolve when solving matrix(with random integers from 3 to 150 in each position) that are 10x10,20x20,30x30, ... , 150x150
for the first 7 I get " 0. " as the result. Is there any way for the command to tell me more exact values, with more decimals?
Also, for the matrix of 80x80 and more I get the same result of 0.015625. Is this normal for the command to take the same time to solve these different matrix?

Comment: Note that timings measured with `Timing` also involve time spent in the frontend. It is more reasonable to use `AbsoluteTiming`. You should use `RepeatedTiming` for more accurate measurements: It runs the code several times and returns the  average runtime. This way, some artifacts can be averaged out. Note also that every timing below, say a millisecond, should not be taken too seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to properly investigate this let's write a quick benchmarking function, like:

```
test[n_, tf_] := Block[{m, b},
   m = RandomInteger[{3, 150}, {n, n}];
   b = RandomInteger[{3, 150}, n];
   First@tf[LinearSolve[m, b]]];
```

`test` takes an argument that determines the matrix size (`n`) and the timing function `tf`. `Timing`, `AbsoluteTiming`, and `RepeatedTiming` are the most commonly used. On my machine:

```
Table[test[n, Timing], {n, 10, 150, 10}]
```

> {0., 0., 0., 0.0156001, 0., 0.0156001, 0., 0.0156001, 0., 0.0156001, 0., 0.0156001, 0.0156001, 0., 0.0156001}

`Timing` demonstrates the same results as you mentioned.

```
Table[test[n, AbsoluteTiming], {n, 10, 150, 10}]
```

> {0.000288766, 0.000618198, 0.00138239, 0.000902868, 0.00133938, 0.00194295, 0.00266179, 0.00352633, 0.00452429, 0.00542013, 0.00635167, 0.0108645, 0.0140152, 0.0164415, 0.0189912}

`AbsoluteTiming` seems to give the precision we want, but repeated testing of it will likely show a fair bit of variation.

```
Table[test[n, RepeatedTiming[#, 5] &], {n, 10, 150, 10}]
```

> {5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 
>    5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 
>    5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9, 5.4*10^-9}

And `RepeatedTiming` shows us something that at first glance might seem odd. It seems that the result is being cached, so repeatedly timing the same `LinearSolve` expression gives, on average, very little time.

Since you're probably primarily concerned with how long it takes to initially generate the solution, it seems like `AbsoluteTiming` is the way to go for this problem.

Note however that `Timing` and `AbsoluteTiming` are fundamentally limited by the timing mechanisms available to your CPU. In most cases, that's going to be millisecond scales (you can check with `$TimeUnit`), so as Henrik Schumacher commented, timings smaller than 1ms are probably not super trustworthy.

Comment: You may want to look also at the `$TimeUnit` documentation.

Comment: @FJRA Thanks, added it to the answer.